# Can ASP.NET Core 6 webAPI run in .NET 4.X Runtimes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

What to do if I spent a whole month developing an intranet `ASP.NET Core 6 webAPI` and then knew that our web server doesn't have .NET 6 installed ? (we have .NET 4.x installed)
(it is not easy to just install `.NET 6` in my case, many approvals to install a single thing)

csproject file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MimeKit" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Well, you can _try_ to downgrade. Or put a spell on your IT, maybe bake some Cookies and beg really hard ... And have a serious word with the guy who gave you the requirements (and missed the one about the target runtime).

Comment: I would say No.  It is not backward compatible with 4.x.  However, you could develop most libraries with .netstandard2.0 which will support some 4.x frameworks and then have your UI in MVC.

Comment: You code is probably using IMAP to read the inbox.  IMAP I do not think is being support in Core.